# divide aggregation - precision mongo db

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, precision

How to specify precision in divide aggregation with mongo DB?

```
Ex. Column : {$divide: ['$Column', 100]},
```

If column value is 123456 then O/P is: **12.3456**
But, I want only two precision as O/P: **12.34**

Also, If column value is 123666 then O/P should be: **12.37**.

**Note: without using any, extra mathematical operation.**

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482623/rounding-to-2-decimal-places-using-mongodb-aggregation-framework

Comment: @achuth , without using any, extra mathematical operation.

Comment: @Nitul: Given these constraints, you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using any, extra mathematical operation, you can't specify precision in divide aggregation.