# Get percentages with MongoDB aggregate $group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'd like to get percentages from a group pipeline in a MongoDB aggregate.

My data:

```js
{
    _id : 1,
    name : 'hello',
    type : 'big'
},
{
    _id : 2,
    name : 'bonjour',
    type : 'big'
},
{
    _id : 3,
    name : 'hi',
    type : 'short'
},
{
    _id : 4,
    name : 'salut',
    type : 'short'
},
{
    _id : 5,
    name : 'ola',
    type : 'short'
}
```

My request group by type, and count:

```js
[{
    $group : {
        _id : {
            type : '$type'
        },
        "count" : {
            "$sum" : 1
        }
    }
}]
```

Result:

```js
[
    {
        _id {
            type : 'big',
        },
        count : 2
    },
    {
        _id {
            type : 'short',
        },
        count : 3
    }
]
```

But I'd like to have count AND percentage, like that:

```js
[
    {
        _id {
            type : 'big',
        },
        count: 2,
        percentage: 40%
    },
    {
        _id {
            type : 'short',
        },
        count: 3,
        percentage: 60%
    }
]
```

But I've no idea how to do that. I've tried `$divide` and other things, but without success. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 16):

Well  I think `percentage` should be string if the value contains `%`

First get you will need to `count` the number of document.

```js
var nums = db.collection.count();

db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { "$group": { "_id": {"type":  "$type"}, "count": { "$sum": 1 }}},    
        { "$project": { 
            "count": 1, 
            "percentage": { 
                "$concat": [ { "$substr": [ { "$multiply": [ { "$divide": [ "$count", {"$literal": nums }] }, 100 ] }, 0,2 ] }, "", "%" ]}
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

*Result*

```js
{ "_id" : { "type" : "short" }, "count" : 3, "percentage" : "60%" }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "big" }, "count" : 2, "percentage" : "40%" }
```

Comment: how do I round of the percentage value to two decimals? In your solution, if the 'percentage' value is 16.66, it will return only '16%', what edits should I make in your solution so that it returns '16.70%' ?

Comment: @TonyMathew to round the percentage look at [`$round`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/round/) new in 4.2 or see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22577649/3100115)

Comment: could you please on this one too ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61145727/count-based-on-condition-and-divide-by-of-records-for-time-interval

Answer (score 9):

First find total number of documents in collections using `count` method and used that count variable to calculate `percentage` in aggregation like this :

```
var totalDocument = db.collectionName.count() //count total doc.
```

used `totalDocument` in aggregation as below :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({"$group":{"_id":{"type":"$type"},"count":{"$sum":1}}},
                            {"$project":{"count":1,"percentage":{"$multiply":[{"$divide":[100,totalDocument]},"$count"]}}})
```

**EDIT**

If you need to this in single `aggregation` query then `unwind` used in aggregation but using `unwind` it creates `Cartesian problem` check below aggregation query :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({"$group":{"_id":null,"count":{"$sum":1},"data":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}}},
                            {"$unwind":"$data"},
                             {"$group":{"_id":{"type":"$data.type"},"count":{"$sum":1},
                                       "total":{"$first":"$count"}}},
                             {"$project":{"count":1,"percentage":{"$multiply":[{"$divide":[100,"$total"]},"$count"]}}}
                            ).pretty()
```

I recconmed first find out toatal count and used that count in aggregation as per first query.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, it sounds like it's not possible to have the result with just one aggregate.

Comment: yes is possible in one aggregation check **EDIT** but problem with in one aggregation it `unwind` data and create a multiple documents.