# Aggregate with group's percent of total and lookup field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am attempting to use Mongoose to group the documents in a Mongo collection by a certain field and return both a lookup value from that field and the percentage of the total collection that documents of this type represent.

Given the following collections:

**Orders**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5acdee5b80a4d21726f4fbaa"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-04-11T11:15:40.104Z"),
    "orderType" : ObjectId("5a6cf47415621604942386aa")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5acdee5b80a4d21726f4fcbb"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-04-12T17:43:11.317Z"),
    "orderType" : ObjectId("5a6cf47415621604942386aa")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aba3a931cef621bd3b74ed7"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-04-16T12:22:18.117Z"),
    "orderType" : ObjectId("5a6cf47415621604942386aa")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5acdee5b80a4d21726f4fb70"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-04-19T08:13:01.223Z"),
    "orderType" : ObjectId("5a6cf47415621604942386bb")
}
```

**OrderType**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6cf47415621604942386aa"),
    "name" : "Order Type 1"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6cf47415621604942386bb"),
    "name" : "Order Type 2"
}
```

I would like the resulting data to look something like this:

```
{
    "orderType" : "Order Type 1",
    "numOrders" : 3,
    "percent" : 75
},
{
    "orderType" : "Order Type 2",
    "numOrders" : 1,
    "percent" : 25
}
```

My code is as follows:

```
  //retrieve the total number of documents in the collection 
  let total = 0;
  await models.orders.count({}).exec((err, cnt) => {
    total = cnt.valueOf();
  });

  await models.orders.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$orderType",
          ordersCount: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: { 
          from: "OrderType", 
          localField: "orderType", 
          foreignField: "_id", 
          as: "orderType" }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          type: "$orderType.name",
          orderCount: "$totalCount",
          percent: { $multiply: [{$divide: [100, total]}, "$totalCount"]}
        }
      }
    ],(err, orders) => {
      orders.map(order => {
        //order.type is undefined here
        console.log("order type: " + order.type);
        console.log("order count: " + order.orderCount);
        console.log("order %: " + order.percent);
      })
    });
```

I was able to use the answer given in [Get percentages with MongoDB aggregate $group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188966/get-percentages-with-mongodb-aggregate-group?rq=1#) to get the orderCount and percent calculations working, but type field in my projection is coming back as undefined.

I am fairly new to Mongoose and the aggregate pipeline.  Is what I am trying to do possible?  If so, what do I need to change about my approach?

Comment: There's nothing wrong here. Getting the "total count" in a separate query would be the most efficient and "safe" thing to do here. Horrible would be attempting to "mush" all your results into a single document in order to simply get that "total count". The only thing you really should improve is use an `$arrayElemAt: [ "$orderType.name", 0 ]` to get the "singular" value. Or really learn the lesson that this would be better off stored in the "orders" themselves, rather than even using `$lookup`. That "join" has a cost which you really should avoid.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it really belongs on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as there is no problem in the code and the question merely asks for review/improvements

Comment: @NeilLunn : Thanks, after applying your suggestion to use $arrayElemAt in the projection I was able to determine the actual source of my problem.  The localField in my $lookup was configured to pull from orders.orderType when in fact I think it needed to get the value from the _id field produced by the $group step.  Once I made this change I was able to retrieve the values.  I will follow up on codereview for the query improvements.