# MongoDB: How to get N decimals precision in a query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, precision

Given the following documents in a MongoDB collection...

```
{ "_id": 1, "amount": { "value": 1.123456789999, "rate": 1.2 }}
{ "_id": 2, "amount": { "value": 2.9844, "rate": 1.2 }}
{ "_id": 3, "amount": { "value": 1.123876, "rate": 1.2 }}
{ "_id": 4, "amount": { "value": 3.3557886, "rate": 1.2 }}
{ "_id": 5, "amount": { "value": 1.12599976, "rate": 1.2 }}
```

... is it possible to select all those documents where `amount` is **1.12** (i.e. get 2 decimals precision in the query)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rounding to 2 decimal places using MongoDB aggregation framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482623/rounding-to-2-decimal-places-using-mongodb-aggregation-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [**`$where`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/where/) operator.

```js
db.collection.find({ "$where": function() { 
    return Math.round(this.amount.value * 100)/ 100 === 1.12; 
    }
})
```

---

EDIT (after [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/53439995?noredirect=1))

In this case you should use the aggregation framework especially the [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator and this is much faster than the solution using `$where`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [
                { "$subtract": [ 
                    "$amount.value", 
                    { "$mod": [ "$amount.value",  0.01 ] }
                ]}, 
                0.03
            ]}, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
     }}
])
```

Comment: In my real collection, amount is nested field... but `Math.round(this.amount.value * 100)/100` doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: It should work. Why didn't you show the exact structure of your document in the first place? Please edit your question to show the exact structure.

Comment: OK... updated my post with the real `amount` structure.

Comment: `this.amount.value` works perhaps you are not using the right collection

Comment: Like this it work `Math.round(this.amount.value * 100.0) / 100.0`... event if  what I'm looking for is `db.orders.find({ "$where": function() { return this.amount.value - (this.amount.value % 0.01) === 0.03; }})` - see my answer. Tx anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively doing a range query where `1.12 <= value < 1.13`, so you could do this as:

```js
db.test.find({'amount.value': {$gte: 1.12, $lt: 1.13}})
```

Which is a truncation to 2 decimal places. If you want to round it, you'd be looking for `1.115 <= value < 1.125`:

```js
db.test.find({'amount.value': {$gte: 1.115, $lt: 1.125}})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the regex operator

```
db.test.find({ value: { $regex: 1\.12[0-9]*}})
```

Comment: Regular expressions only work on strings and not numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the answer I got from [user3100115](http://user3100115), here below is the final soluton:

```
db.orders.find({ "$where": function() { return this.amount.value - (this.amount.value % 0.01) === 0.03; }})
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: In this case you should use aggregation and the `$redact` operator. Edited my answer to add that.