# Rounding to 2 decimal places in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, mongodb-query

I have my collection as

**Student**

```
{
    "first_name":"Harew",
    "last_name":"Jackson",
    "class":14,
    "fee": [
        { "tuition":48500.2456, "transportation":500 }
    ]
}
```

I need to filter student according to `fee = 4500.24` and it should display
all the students having fee 4500.24 ignoring other digits after the decimal point.

I have searched in [MongoDB: How to get N decimals precision in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798386/mongodb-how-to-get-n-decimals-)
precision-in-a-query but the solution provided here does not work in my scenario since 
   `"$mod": [ "$amount.value",  0.01 ]` is not applicable for `BigDecimal` type and in my collection I have fee type as `BigDecimal`.

The following solution seems to work well but I don't know how to implement this in Scala

```
db.collection.find({ 
    "$where": function() { 
        return Math.round(this.fee.school * 100)/ 100 === 1.12; 
    }
})
```

Comment: 48500.2456 is not be equals to 48500.24 and shouldn't be used in query. However for reporting purpose, you can round it to your choice. FYI 48500.2456 rounds to 48500.25 not 48500.24

Answer (score 1):

you can easily round up the values into specific precision from BigDecimal , also if you want you can convert it into double value at the same time .
For Example : -

scala> val s :BigDecimal = 10.232
s: BigDecimal = 10.232

scala> **s.setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble**
res1: Double = 10.23       // CONVERTED AS DOUBLE

scala> **s.setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)**
res2: scala.math.BigDecimal = 10.23   // Rouding Off

So in scala instead of using math.Round you can use setScale.

Comment: I have already tried this. But it did not work. It roundup the value but did not match with the value in database. For example my database has tuition fee value 48500.2456 but after doing this I get 48500.24 but does not match the data of database

Comment: sorry I didnt get your point , you told that you are converting the value coming from the DB , i.e say 48500.2456 to 48500.24 , but then you said that it does not match the data of database . Which data are we now talking about . Are you converting the data from db as well as the matching value properly in BigDecimals .

Comment: I have 48500.2456 in database now what I want is I want to match the student whose fee is 48500.24 by querying in scala

Comment: Ok . so use the below code : -  48500.2456.setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.FLOOR) == 48500.24 .  Where 48500.2456 is your value from DB.