# Mongodb query for matching whole number(456789.98745) in db while sending only number with 2 number after decimal part(456789.98)

Tags: mongodb, scala

The query below is for rounding to 2 decimal place and matching the whole number in db for example (in db 456789.98745 is matched by 456789.98 send in request).
But How can we query this in scala. I found this in [MongoDB: How to get N decimals precision in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798386/mongodb-how-to-get-n-decimals-precision-in-a-query)

`db.collection.find({ "$where": function() { 
    return Math.round(this.amount.value * 100)/ 100 === 1.12; 
    }
})`

I have tried above query in mongodb but I cannot find the way to query in scala
I have my document as 
Student{
"first_name":"abc",
"last_name":"xyz",
"amount":450000.23456
}
I need a query which match 450000.23456 in db when I pass 450000.23 as filtering value in url

Comment: Show us what you tried. At least the query without the filtering working properly.

Comment: Do you know that Scala has libs to talk to MongoDB - The official `Mongo-Scala-Driver` or community `ReactiveMongo`