# Rounding floats within an aggregate function in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to do this within the `$project` array using **PHP**'s built in `round` function?

I try to enclose my output value within the `round` function to *2* decimal places:

```
"Energy" => round(array('$multiply' => array("$energy", 10)), 2),
```

The output error I get is this:

> Type: MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException
>
> Code: 16406
>
> Message: The top-level _id field is the only field currently supported for exclusion
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\DRM\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Operation\Aggregate.php
> Line: 168

Currently I have a separate parsing method which takes care of all the rounding, but what I'd like is to do it within the aggregate function in PHP.

Is this possible? I know MongoDB doesn't have round, but there is an external library for that.

Comment: `round` takes a `float` not an array, so that can't be helping matters.

Comment: perhaps I'm misunderstanding something on a fundamental level, but when I don't have the round function my output in JSON is "Energy": 323.2222 which is a float right?

Comment: @JonStirling this constructor is specific to mongo php driver

Comment: @profesor79 What constructor? And what does that have to do with the `round` function?

Answer (score 1):

there is no runding capabilities for mongo yet.

[as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22577649/5919473), you could add extra steps to aggregation pipeline to get it rounded - below mongo shell code:

```
> db.a.save({x:1.23456789})
> db.a.save({x:9.87654321})
> db.a.aggregate([{$project:{ _id:0, 
         y:{$divide:[
              {$subtract:[
                      {$multiply:['$x',100]},
                      {$mod:[{$multiply:['$x',100]}, 1]}
              ]},
              100]}
}}])
{ "y" : 1.23 }
{ "y" : 9.87 }
```

[jira ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15926)