# MongoDB - How to Truncate Float Values to One or Two decimal points in aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say this is the query:

```
db.movies.aggregate([
  {$match: {languages: "English", cast:{$exists:true}}},

  {$unwind: "$cast"},

  {$group: {_id: "$cast", numFilms:{$sum: 1}, average:{$avg: "$imdb.rating"}   
  }},

  {$sort: {numFilms:-1}},

  {$limit: 1}
])
```

And I get the output:

```
{ "_id" : "John Wayne", "numFilms" : 107, "average" : 6.424299065420561 }
```

How can I truncate `average` to single/double decimal points? I wanted to see an output like this:

```
{ "_id" : "John Wayne", "numFilms" : 107, "average" : 6.42 }
```

I tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482623/rounding-to-2-decimal-places-using-mongodb-aggregation-framework), but seems like I can't get away doing the same with `$avg` operator. How can I achieve this?

### Potential duplicate

I believe the above linked isn't a duplicate, because mine deals with `$avg` operator.

Comment: Just would like to mention that both truncate/round decimals would suit for me just in case only rounding is possible. I couldnt find the latter case too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding to 2 decimal places using MongoDB aggregation framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482623/rounding-to-2-decimal-places-using-mongodb-aggregation-framework)

Comment: My question is different, if u read my question properly, I'm looking for an answer where `$avg` operator can still be used unlike the other post which I clearly mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this with a `$project` stage with a `$trunc` but `$multiply` before and `$divide` after to deal with the decimal places.

For example if we add the following:

```
db.test.insertMany([{
    number: 123.456
}, {
    number: 456.789
}, {
    number: 123
}]);
```

We can run an aggregation with the following:

```
db.test.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        number: {
            $divide: [{
                $trunc: {
                    $multiply: ["$number", 100]
                }
            }, 100]
        }
    }
}])
```

Which will give us:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ab23dcb8094b7e4427b43f3"), "number" : 123.45 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ab23dcb8094b7e4427b43f4"), "number" : 456.78 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ab23dcb8094b7e4427b43f5"), "number" : 123 }
```

Comment: So you mean no way to truncate/round with `avg` operator?

Comment: There is no option on `$avg` operator to round, so you'd have to do this as a separate stage after the `$group` stage,

Comment: See my answer to existing question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482623/rounding-to-2-decimal-places-using-mongodb-aggregation-framework/49412882#49412882

Comment: @KevinSmith
Thank you for the info.

Comment: Have you tried average: `{$avg: {             $divide: [{                 $trunc: {                     $multiply: ["$number", 100]                 }             }, 100]         }}` ?

Comment: **UPDATE:** The `$trunc` usage has changed since v4.2. Now you just have to do`$trunc:['$number',2]` to get 2 decimal precision.

Answer (score 0):

```
$project : {
    artistAmt : {
        $divide: [{
            $trunc: {
                $multiply: ["$earnedAmount", 100]
            }
        }, 100]
    }
}    
before : "artistAmt": 1361.8100000000002
after : "artistAmt": 1361.81
```

Comment: Please provide a description that explains your solution