# Round decimal to nearest integer in MongoDB aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, rounding

I have gone through below site but Can't get my solution.
[Round to 2 decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482623/rounding-to-2-decimal-places-using-mongodb-aggregation-framework)

I have below decimals and want to round to nearest integer:

```
34.56 => 35
34.67 => 35
34.12 => 34
```

I have tried this:

```
            "$subtract": [
                        "$x",
                        { "$mod": ["$x", 1] }
                    ]
```

Same like in **Oracle Round function**

How can I do in MongoDB?

Comment: Mongodb soon introducing [**$round**](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/round/) aggregation operator. You still have to wait.

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB is introducing [$round](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/round/#exp._S_round) in 4.2. As a workaround you can use [$floor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/floor/index.html) and [$ceil](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ceil/index.html) conditionally checking if the fraction part is greater that 0.5

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            x: { 
                $cond: [ 
                    { $gte: [ { $subtract: [ "$x", { $floor: "$x" } ] }, 0.5 ] }, 
                    { $ceil: "$x" }, 
                    { $floor: "$x" } 
                ] 
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hD0ae925euc)

Comment: Any idea on when 4.2 might be released?