# How to divide two numbers and get the result in whole numbers MONGODB

Tags: php, mongodb, project

I want to divide `two` numbers in `mongoDB` `project` and fetch the result in whole numbers.

```
'average'=> ['$divide'=> [['$trunc'=>['$add'=> [['$multiply'=> [['$divide'=>['$total_revenue','$count']], 100]], 0.5]]], 100]],
```

The following code gives the result to upto 2 decimal places , but i want the answer in a whole number

Comment: You can use php `round()`, `ceil()`, `floor()` any one function to convert it into whole number.

Comment: i dont think there is `round` in mongo . Also `floor` will return the lowest value . for eg : `{ $floor: 7.80 }` wil 7. but it should be 8l

Comment: use `ceil()`, but again that is php function

Comment: i am actually looking for a solution in mongo

Comment: You need to use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trunc/

Comment: Or:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482623/rounding-to-2-decimal-places-using-mongodb-aggregation-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$ceil`

For ex:

```
averageSkill:{ $ceil:{$multiply:[{$divide:[{$divide:["$skill","$count"]},5]},100]}},
```