# MongoDB decimal rounder

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I used morphia for MongoDB aggregation to data. but I need to round my aggregation pipeline projection data. my code is

```
 aggregationPipeline.project(
            Projection.projection("_id").suppress(),
            Projection.projection("query", "_id.query"),
            Projection.projection("clicks", "clicks"),
            Projection.projection("impressions", "impressions"),
            Projection.projection("ctr",  "ctr"),
            Projection.projection("position", "position")
);
```

My Output is

```
{
        "query": "google",          
        "clicks": 5,
        "impressions": 16,
        "ctr": 0.19375,
        "position": 3.39375,          
},
```

but i expect that

```
{
        "query": "google",          
        "clicks": 5,
        "impressions": 16,
        "ctr": 0.19,
        "position": 3.39,          
},
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding to 2 decimal places using MongoDB aggregation framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482623/rounding-to-2-decimal-places-using-mongodb-aggregation-framework)

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55170342/4308032