# Convert month from number to string question in Mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to get some avg number per month in the financial year. The collection is called test and the month data comes from `CreateDate` field. I want to get the avg price per month. The collection data is like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fd289a93f7cf02c36837ca7"),
    "ClientName" : "John",
    "OrderNumber" : "12345A",
    "Price" : 10,
    "CreateDate" : ISODate("2020-09-20T06:00:00.000Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fd289a93f7cf02c36837cc7"),
    "ClientName" : "John",
    "OrderNumber" : "12345",
    "Price" : 20,
    "CreateDate" : ISODate("2020-09-12T06:00:00.000Z"),
}
```

So I am writing the query to get the avg number per month by the following within the financial year (from Sep to Aug):

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "CreateDate": {
        $lt: ISODate("2021-08-31T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $gte: ISODate("2020-09-01T00:00:00.000Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {$month: "$CreateDate"}, 
      "AvgPrice": {
        "$avg": "$Price",
      } 
    }
  },
  { $project:{ _id : 0 , Month: '$_id' , "AvgPrice ": '$AvgPrice' } } 
])
```

The result I am getting is with the following format:

```
{
    "Month" : 9,
    "AvgPrice " : 15.0
}
{
    "Month" : 10,
    "AvgPrice " : 18.6666666666667
}
```

How can I display of the month converting to a string instead of the number. For example, the following is the ideal return:

```
{
    "Month" : Sep,
    "AvgPrice" : 15.0
}
{
    "Month" : Oct,
    "AvgPrice" : 18.6666666666667
}
```

I also have two more questions:

1. I am using the Mongodb 3.6 version, is there any way to round up the avg price to two digit after the decimal point? For example, above will be "18.67" instead of "18.66666".  Mongo 4.2 has something called `$round` but 3.6 seems doesn't have this function.
2. If I want to break down by client, has the returning result like below:

```
{
    "ClientName": "John",
    "Month" : Sep,
    "AvgPrice" : 15.0
}
{  
    "ClientName" : "Mary"
    "Month" : Oct,
    "AvgPrice" : 18.6666666666667
}
```

How do I put another level of the group to breakdown to the client level and then month level?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: you have too many questions, it would be easy if you specific with one. 1) you have already answer got `$round`, there is no any other option in 3.6.

Comment: Thanks @turivishal . You are always so helpful. I can only post one post in an hour so I am thinking to save time to put all the questions together. So now I am having two questions, 1.  how to convert the month from numbers to string, for example, 9 to Sep. 2. How to break down by the client and the month to get the avg number. Right now the code is breaking down by month. I am testing some code it shows up the ClientName but the calculation is wrong. The query is too long so I can't paste here. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *If I want to break down by client*

You can add `ClientName` field in `_id`,

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        ClientName: "$ClientName",
        month: { $month: "$CreateDate" }
      },
      AvgPrice: { $avg: "$Price" }
    }
  },
```

> *How can I display of the month converting to a string instead of the number.*

There is no any straight way to get month name in mongodb, but if you prepare array of months in string and access it by index,

- `$arrayElemAt` to select month by its number

```
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      ClientName: "$_id.ClientName",
      Month: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          ["","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],
          "$_id.month"
        ]
      },
      AvgPrice: 1
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mVoSgfkc2wm)

> *I am using the Mongodb 3.6 version, is there any way to round up the avg price to two digit after the decimal point?*

There is no any option in mongodb 3.6 or below, you already know there is a option `$round` in mongodb 4.2.

You can refer this question [Rounding to 2 decimal places using MongoDB aggregation framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482623/rounding-to-2-decimal-places-using-mongodb-aggregation-framework)
, there are many tricks.

Comment: Thanks @turivishal. It is very helpful. The group break down part: I have the result set like this:

{
    "AvgPrice" : 15.0,
    "ClientName" : "John",
    "Month" : "Sep"
}
{
    "AvgPrice" : 18.6666666666667,
    "ClientName" : "John",
    "Month" : "Oct"
}
Is there anyway to have result like below:
{
    "AvgClient" : "John",
    "AvgMonth" : [ 
        {
            "Month" : Sep,
            "avgmonth" : 15.0
        }, 
        {
            "Month" : Oct,
            "avgmonth" : 17.4
        }, 
] ? So it is like having the ClientName on the top of the array.

Comment: no there is no straight way check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks so much @turivishal. Your help is much appreciated!